# Como fazer uma rotina,funcao em vb.net que executa em um horario definido?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, asp

Olá preciso de ajuda com vb.net em uma aplicação asp.net, preciso criar uma função que roda apos a 24 horas para fechamento de operações, mais não tenho a minima ideia de como criar uma função que inicia sozinha em um período de tempo.

Comment: tem várias formas, mas o agendador de tarefas do `windows` é uma forma simples de fazer isso

Comment: Na verdade eles tem um programa de schedulle para varias funções mais ninguém tinha me passado nada de como seria estava totalmente perdido.Então eu só crio a biblioteca e chamo ela por um console aplication, eles startam a minha console no schedulle.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Existem várias maneiras de resolver este problema, mas eu sugiro uma bem simples e fácil de implementar.

Crie uma aplicação do tipo Console Application no seu projeto. É aconselhável que toda o executável seja apenas o invocador da sua lógica que deveria residir em um namespace próprio. Este Console App irá gerar um Executável que pode ser acionado manualmente.

No Servidor onde for instalado, crie uma tarefa agendada no Gerenciador de Tarefas Agendadas (Task Scheduler) (Win+R -> taskschd.msc), e configure para executar nos dias e horários desejados, apontando para o seu executável.

Utilize arquivos de LOGs para descrever as sequências importantes das operações, e principalmente, identificar possíveis problemas na sua rotina.